# How to retrieve All attributes of given user from given group in ActiveDirectory using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

Can anyone help me to get All Attributes of given user in given group  from active-directory using Vb Script .

On Error Resume Next

```
Set objGroup = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=IMTS,DC=TEST")
objGroup.GetInfo

arrMemberOf = objGroup.GetEx("member")

WScript.Echo "Members:"
For Each strMember in arrMemberOf
    WScript.echo strMember.distinguishedName
Next
```

This is giving me only users in group but i want all attributes on given user

eg:

```
    Account_Expires: 
Account_Name_History: 
CS_PolicyName: 
Admin_Count: 
Admin_Description: 
Admin_DisplayName: 
AllowedAttributes: 
AllowedAttributesEffective: 
Allowed_Child_Classes: 
AllowedChildClassesEffective: 
AltSecurityIdentities: 
AttributeCertificateAttribute: 
Audio: 
Bad_Password_Time: 
Bad_Pwd_Count: 
Bridge_head_ServerListBL: 
BusinessCategory: 
C: 
canonicalName: 
carLicense: 
co:
```

So on
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**note**: Sorry, I'm not in an environment where I could test it and all this answer is just a memory exercise. I hope it can help

You could try to query the LDAP schema for the User class

```
Set oSchema = GetObject("LDAP://schema/user")
```

Then, you can iterate over the `MandatoryProperties` and `OptionalProperties` collections storing the retrieved values to later check your users for these attributes

```
Set oAttributesList = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each strAttribute In oSchema.MandatoryProperties
    oAttributesList.Add strAttribute, ""
Next 
For Each strAttribute In oSchema.OptionalProperties
    oAttributesList.Add strAttribute, ""
Next
```

And once you have the full list, you could use `GetEx` to retrieve (as an array) the value of each of the attributes for each of the users

```
Set objGroup = GetObject _
  ("LDAP://CN=Domain Admins,CN=Users,DC=IMTS,DC=TEST")
objGroup.GetInfo

arrMemberOf = objGroup.GetEx("member")

WScript.Echo "Members:"
For Each strMember in arrMemberOf
    Set oMember = GetObject("LDAP://" & strMember)
    For Each strAttribute in oAttributesList.Keys
        WScript.Echo strAttribute
        aData = oMember.GetEx(strAttribute)
        For i = 0 to UBound(aData)
            WScript.Echo "....: " & aData(i)
        Next 
        WScript.Echo ""
    Next
Next
```

Comment: the above script was throwing the following error. kindly help on this?
Members: cn Microsoft VBScript runtime error (21, 9) : Object required: 'strMember' Microsoft VBScript runtime error (22, 9) : Type mismatch: 'UBound'

Comment: strMember is not a Object .

Comment: @user3883423,Sorry, my fault. I didn't read carefully your code and didn't realize you were iterating over the names. As Ansgar Wiechers points, once you have the identitiy of the member (a string) it is necessary to retrieve the corresponding object from the LDAP and then query its properties.